# Factory girl create list count not right

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I use FactoryGril created two users, both with 3 events:

```
    let (:user) {FactoryGirl.create :user,:with_events}
    let (:user1) {FactoryGirl.create :user,:with_events}
```

But i get all events count 6, but i got 3,

```
Failure/Error: expect(json["events"].count).to eq 6

       expected: 6
            got: 3

       (compared using ==)
```

Thanks!

**Factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do |f|

  factory :user do
    password      "123123"
    sequence(:name){|n| "张三#{n}" }
  end

  factory :event do 
    end_date      "2015-05-30"
    is_countdown  "1"
  end


  trait :with_events do
    after :create do |user|
      FactoryGirl.create_list :event, 3, :user => user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It will be nice if you can post how do you build the json, or where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Note that let is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first time
the method it defines is invoked. You can use let! to force the method's
invocation before each example.
```

Change `let!` replace `let` make it!